When an operator with variable coefficient is bounded?
When the operator $Au(x):=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(m(x,\xi)\widehat{u}(\xi))(x)$ is bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
I know that, by Mikhlin theorem, if $m(x,\xi)=m(\xi)$ (not dependence on $x$) is a fourier multiplier, then, $A$ is bounded on $L^p$. Why happens in the variable case $m(x,\xi)$?
